# Which ship in Eve is the most suited for supporting a Dust 514 Merc

Tags: eve-online, dust-514

I read from [here](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/EVE-DUST_514_Link_FAQ) that the only thing that

> The only thing that affects the amount of damage done right now is the
>   number of turrets used to perform the strike. The damage modifier, the
>   meta/tech level of the turret, and even the type (blasters vs. railgun
>   f.ex.) do not affect the amount of damage done.

In my mind the best ship would be the one with the most turret hard points. **Assuming that I haven't overlooked anything which ship(s) in Eve have the most turret hard points?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orbital bombardment uses small guns, so there is no need to use large ships for this purpose. From [the orbital bombardement dev blog](http://community.eveonline.com/news/dev-blogs/74180):

> As one might assume, more guns are just better, so I recommend the
>   destroyer hull as the best compromise between damage, mobility and
>   cost for this particular task.

Among the destroyers, only the Catalyst and the Coercer have 8 turrets, so those two seem to be best suited for the task (ignoring the difference between hybrid, projectile and laser turrets for orbital bombardement).

Comment: Does it actually matter how many guns you have? If so, how?

Comment: "The only thing that affects the amount of damage done right now is the number of turrets used to perform the strike."